# Session timing out - bit of explanation please

Tags: php, session, session-timeout

From what I thought I understood from sessions, this should be the case:

- session times out based on what is set in the php.ini, lets say 30
  minutes
- if a user continues to browse and we update, lets say
  $_SESSION['last_activity']=time();, then the session will be active for 30 minutes from the last activity

But what I am seeing is:

- user logs in and session is started
- user continues to browse
- after 30 minutes, user is kicked off and annoyed, has to login again

Is this a server misconfiguration and why it is being destroyed even though the user is remaining active?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` on every page or only on the login page?

Comment: Yes I do start_session(); immediately (the page is the same wherever the user goes as it serves up the sub pages/templates)

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Comment: @RishiKalia That seems to be more about making sure it times out exactly at 30 minutes. That isn't my issue, my issue is if the user is still active, the session shouldn't expire; the session should remain active until the user does nothing for approximately 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling:

```
session_start();
```

on every page that the visitor is accessing. This will reset the session clock.

Comment: I do that on every page (the page is the same everywhere; index.php starts with session_start(); runs a few tasks and serves up the correct template based on the url)